# How to upgrade android app signing certificate if app signing is managed by organisation itself?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, android-app-signing

I have a situation where my current app signing key is lost, now we want to upgrade our current application with new key but
we dont want to upload a new application. We were managing the key by ourself only since its very old app around 10 years old.
I have read the articles were we can request a key upgrade but that is not applicable for me as singing key is not managed by Google.

I have also came through Key rotation provision from Android 9+  but that is not yet possible to upload on Play store.
I don't have any idea if we can request google to allow us to upgrade our app with new signing key without uploading new app.

Let me know if there is any way we can use?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use Play Signing and you lost your signing key, then your only option is to create a new app / a new package name.

Comment: They can talk to Google and manage to keep the same listing with a new key, but every existing user will need to uninstall and reinstall to get updates.

Comment: I don't think that Google can do that though (or even would want to allow this to happen since that would be quite a confusing experience for users).

Comment: They can and do do that.  It was all they could do back before Google Play Signing existed.

Comment: Do you have a source? I've worked on Play Signing and have never heard of such process.

Comment: You reach out to then.  I know multiple developers who have done this over the past decade when they lost their keys.  Granted its probably a bit of a crap shoot given that Google has the worst customer service of any company in history.

Comment: The process you describe sounds a lot like an "Upload key reset" described in the section "Lost or compromised upload key?" in [this article](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9842756?hl=en) but this is only possible for apps enrolled in Play Signing.

Comment: THis ability predates play signing by a decade, but its not automated.  It actually requires you to get the attention of their CSRs.